# How to prove some theorems of integration in $\Bbb R^2$ or higher dimension?

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

How should I begin to solve 3A)? I understand that $f$ is continuous on this compact box $[a,b]\times[c,d]$, but how does that relate to $F(x)$ being continuous or even differentiable on $[a,b]$? I understand that the fundamental theorem of calculus states that in $1$ variable if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then $F(x)$, the integral from $a$ to $x$ of $f(x)$, is differentiable on $[a,b]$. But in this case or $\Bbb R^2$, how do I justify $F(x)$, which probably makes all $y$ parts of the $f(x,y)$ function, is differentiability on $[a,b]$? Can someone explain why it still works?

For 3b) I have no clue on where to begin. It just seems unfamiliar to put differentials inside integrals like this.

Comment: Calculus isn’t really my terrain so take the following with a grain of salt. For continuity in 3A I would try to pick an $x$ and a sequence $x_n \rightarrow x$ and show that $F(x_n)\rightarrow F(x)$ by using triangle inequality for integrals. Since $[a,b]$ is bounded this should suffice. The 3B looks to me like an application of Fubini...

Comment: @PrudiiArca, sorry but I don't see how triangle inequality will appear if I use sequences definition of continuity. Can you elaborate on that if possible?

Comment: The calculus way of showing continuity of some function $g: X\rightarrow Y$ is to show that for $x_n \rightarrow x$ it holds that $g(x_n) \rightarrow g(x)$. The latter means to show that for each $\epsilon$ there exists $N$ such that for all $n>N$ we have $\vert g(x_n) - g(x)\vert<\epsilon$. Does that help?